# PHP and MS access not working

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

```
$dbName = "C:\path\folder"; 
$user=""; $password="";

if(!file_exists($dbName)) {
     die("Could not find database file."); 
} echo"connecting...";

$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};
DBQ=$dbName; $user, $password");
```

the above is my connection string code for .mdb, I am running IIS7 on win7. My php page runs perfectly, but when I include or put the connection string above my page, it loads only until the

```
echo"connecting...";
```

and don't load anything under the string ...

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=$dbName; $user, $password");
```

So I transferred the `$db = new PDO()...` in the footer area and everything loads above this string.

Can anyone help me with this crazy problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php), the connection string should be

```
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$dbName", $user, $password);
```

In your case, it should be

```
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};
Dbq=$dbName" $user, $password);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help Friend. I found a working code here. Thanks again, 'till next problem. ^_^

> [Using PHP to query a MDB file, and return JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020493/using-php-to-query-a-mdb-file-and-return-json)
>
> [PDO Query Database ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026002/pdo-query-database-odbc)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have this now.

```
$conn = odbc_connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=Northwind.mdb','','');

if($conn){
    echo "Database Connected!";
} else echo "Database Disconnected.";
```

Hope this will helps those who are new to php and MS Access.

Thanks.